# Weird error with rails atom builder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, atom-feed

I am trying to create a simple atom feed with the respond_to method in rails

I have the respond to and routes set up properly but my builder errors. I have tried everything I can think of so hopefully StackOverflow can tell me what I overlooked

The error that atom builder is giving me is

```
undefined method `post_url' for #<#<Class:0x00000101c8f3a0>:0x00000101c8d460>
```

My builder code is pretty simple

```
atom_feed :language => "en-US" do |feed|
  feed.title SETTINGS[:organization_name]
  feed.updated @posts.first.created_at

  @posts.each do |post|
    feed.entry post do |entry| # this is the loop that causes the error
      feed.title post.name
      feed.content post.contents
      feed.url "/#{post.permalink}"
    end
  end
end
```

As you can see I isolated the loop that causes the error but without that loop I cannot add entries to the atom feed.

Comment: Why do you use `feed.entry post do |entry|` instead of `feed.entry do |entry|`?

Comment: That's what all the examples have had.  I am not sure but if I don't include the post than I get a different error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shouldn't it be:

```
entry.title post.name
entry.content post.contents
entry.url "/#{post.permalink}"
```

I have no idea if this is a typo or if this is the problem you are experiencing. That being said, could you post more of your stacktrace?

Comment: The only other thing I can think of is whether or not your routes are properly defined? `post_url` is typically going to come from there, so what does your routes file look like?

Comment: You helped me solve it.  Routes are all RESTful design and I just had to declare a url in that loop